# Trying to get a Testnet Node Running

Tags: testnet, syncing

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I am trying to get a testnet node running. After syncing for quite a while I get this error:

```
[DESKTOP-:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:70] [2021-08-26 14:36:47.71 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 54.151.49.138:3001 HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 1598400, blockPointHash = 02b1c561715da9e540411123a6135ee319b02f60b9a11a603d3305556c04329f})) (HeaderProtocolError (HardForkValidationErrFromEra S (Z (WrapValidationErr {unwrapValidationErr = ChainTransitionError [OverlayFailure (VRFKeyBadNonce (Nonce "81e47a19e6b29b0a65b9591762ce5143ed30d0261e5d24a3201752506b20f15c") (SlotNo 1598400) (Nonce "e209c5d22fe51d58485759cc9edca776cb505c1afb2ba5f98f8a6a979a7589e4") (CertifiedVRF {certifiedOutput = OutputVRF {getOutputVRFBytes = "t\231\145\196\165ZhA\137S\209{Z<1\194\225]Yq\235\&7#!\161:\147\129Q\236x\207\195z\170\155\182mw\141\182\135\249\209\178\134\&3_:\167b\135\204\&4\205Z\172\230\163\226\EM\DC2\226\182"}, certifiedProof = CertPraosVRF "!\202\180:L)*\DC2\250\SOH\141V \240Z\EOT\n\183\245\141\SUB\191\ETXQ\"\EOT\155A\SOH'\160LD\253\204Z\249\129/i\178\237p\155\140\240\142\183)LG\137q\248\DLE\DC1\130W\183\162\149\DEL6=[5\225/18\154\192=\242\255\181\f\190\190\t"}))]})))) (Tip (SlotNo 1598271) 4b9ea00e776ff866b1e562bc41ea5531090aaa2991891579b32ce691d8b684c6 (BlockNo 1597004)) (Tip (SlotNo 35619383) 8cce4530864892c20e2467f349fb3e22bb7965e620c286b9b01c689e94019520 (BlockNo 2861367))
```

Comment: You need to double check your genesis fine is 100% correct. Do not copy paste it, download it. Even one space of difference can be problematic.

Comment: I had changed some values in the config files that solved some other errors I was seeing, but since I do not know enough about how things are setup, I went ahead and started from scratch making sure to download the files as you suggested. Everything is working correctly now. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is because of the genesis file. I will fill it as an answer, please flag it if helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when you genesis file is not matching your peers. Make sure you download the file, without editing. Even a single space of difference will result in a different genesis hash.